# How to call Angular code server-side, from a .Net Core Service

Tags: angular, .net-core, server-side-rendering

This is proving to be a difficult thing to research because everyone's first response to similar questions is, "what the heck are you doing?".  Here's exactly what we are trying to do...

We are developing a .Net Core service that will trigger some workflow when a certain Kafka message shows up.  It will go grab some data, then it will need to generate some html from that data, then it will convert that html to a PDF and save that on a file server.  We don't need a browser, at least not a visible one, and we certainly won't have a user.  This should all happen server-side.

The kicker is that we have Angular code, and some hefty third-party modules along with it, that handle the "generate some html" step perfectly.  It would be very elegant to be able to re-use it.  We just need a black box to accept data and spit out html.  It would be a serious pain to have to write that "generate html" black box in C#.

I'm about to start researching Angular Universal and server-side rendering, but I wanted to see if anyone here has done anything like this and can save us some time with the benefit of your experience.  Of particular interest is how to trigger the Angular functionality from .Net.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ** Angular code, and some hefty third-party modules along with it**?  Is it a component, a service that can not be isolated and create a library? Why not using the modules along nodejs or something like expressjs.  You can easily create an api to create PDFs, HTML, etc.

Comment: This seems like a disaster waiting to happen, either find a C# nuget that handles generation of PDFs from HTML (of which there are legion, some are also free) or leverage nodeJS as a_e recommends. 

In essence your request is to have the .NET send some sort of message and have the angular side listen to those messages (so it will need to poll a message queue X amount of times per minute) to get that message. That is fundamental mismatch of the two technologies you have at your disposal

Comment: We have a third party module that provides a component that can be placed in a template - that component can render the lion's share of our html.  I've started looking at Angular's static generation capabilities, and I like the idea of exposing that via some Nodejs api.

Comment: I think it's using the best technology for each task.  Angular is much better suited for rendering the html than C# is.  I think I just need to package up that capability and expose it via an api.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you need to do is setup SSR indeed

- [.NET Core 3.1 guide](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-update-705c0ec01931)
- [.NET 6 guide](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976)

Then all you have to do is call the angular component url with a query parameter, parse this query parameter, supply it to the ClientApp, inject the value in the component, and render it. Then you can already generate the HTML. You'll still need to covert this html to a pdf though.

Another option (more certain) is to create a razor view to render the html, but then the "other javascript modules" won't be executed...